# mailApp.sendEmail not to current user

Tags: google-apps-script

I was wondering if anyone has advice on how to send emails via MailApp.sendEmail() but not go to the current user.

My script looks something like this:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: employeeEmail + "," + managerEmail,
  subject: "Time card",
  htmlBody: emailBody
});
```

The employees enter their time into a google form, my email sends the email, but I don't need a copy in my inbox.

Comment: Because the email is being sent from your account, you can't stop it from showing up as far as I know. You could create a filter in your inbox to 'mark as read' and archive all emails from you with the subject 'Time card'.

Comment: That was my plan, but if there was a way to just have it show up in my inbox that would be more ideal.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is `managerEmail` your email? Can you simply send the email to `employeeEmail`?

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: employeeEmail,
  subject: "Time card",
  htmlBody: emailBody
});
```

Comment: I am not.  I manage the contractors contracts.  The employees work in several departments under several different managers.  I want the employee and their manager aware of what is being billed against their contract.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry for the simple question. So the issue is about the emails appearing in your "sent" box, right? They don't actually land in your inbox?

Comment: No, they land in my inbox.  Almost like they were sent to me from me.  If they landed in my sent I would be ok with that.

Comment: Hmm. That is not the expected behavior for `MailApp.sendEmail`. You should be able to email others without the email appearing in the sender's inbox. I would double check a copy of the email isn't being sent to you elsewhere in the code, your email isn't accidentally getting appended to `employeeEmail`/ `managerEmail` and other issues like that.

Comment: I have used MailApp.sendEmail before and this is the only time I've seen this happen where the user didn't want the emails sent to their inbox.  I added a "key" for them to use as a filter from their inbox, so that works as a workaround.

Comment: Could this be a change to MailApp.sendEmail had changes made to it?  Another people I know that uses it regularly said they just noticed it starting to happen a couple months ago.